# Find the vector $h_0$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $L(h) = \langle h, h_0 \rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

The following problem was taken from Conway's A course in Functional analysis Section 1.3 problem 2

Let $\mathcal{H} = l^2(\mathbb{N})$. If $N\geq1$ and $L:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is defined by $L(\{\alpha_n\}) = \alpha_N$, find the vector $h_0$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $L(h) = \langle h, h_0 \rangle$ for every $h$ in $\mathcal{H}$.

My solution is below and I wanted to make sure it was correct:

The inner product on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ is defined to be $\langle x, y\rangle = \sum_{n\geq1} x(n)\overline{y(n)}$. So if we let $h_0$ be the vector with all zeroes except for $h_0(N) = 1$. Then $\langle \{\alpha_n\}, h_0\rangle = \alpha_N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. As disappointing as it may sound, I don't really have further comments about it, other than the observation that your $L$ is just a "projection", so the vector equivalent to it should be a vector in the "standard" basis of the space.